Appium inspector is not able to start the session, error appears
Getting below error while trying to connect to Appium server using appium inspector
ErrorFailed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Check https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13802 for throubleshooting. Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\vivek.thapliyal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s CYTKIB6SPN8SIRE6 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy'' exited with code 255'; Command output: Security exception: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:2055) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1114) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.deleteGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1097) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.delete(SettingsProvider.java:679) at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:404) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.deleteForUser(SettingsService.java:406) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:289) at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103) at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShell

Tried with below configurations
{"appium:automationName": "uiautomator2","appium:platformName": "Android","appium:platformVersion": "9","appium:deviceName": "CYTKIB6SPN8SIRE6","appium:app": "D:/Automation/ApiDemos-debug.apk","appium:appium": "ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError"}


You need to put in the Capability Builder the key and value for Appium Inspector
ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError        text           true
